# Mount error: “unknown filesystem type 'exfat'”

Tags: filesystems, mount, fedora, exfat

I'm running Fedora 28 and when I try to mount this SD card, I get the following error:

[image]

The last part of the error message translates to

> unknown filesystem type 'exfat'

If I try to open it using Gnome Disks, I get the following device info:

[image]

Clicking the mount button gives me a nearly identical error screen as before.

I've tried to follow [this Ubuntu-based answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364270/mount-error-unknown-filesystem-type-exfat) but there's no `exfat-fuse`, `exfat-utils`, or `fuse-exfat` packages for Fedora, and I can't use PPAs.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the [rpmfusion-free](https://rpmfusion.org/Configuration) repository and then install `fuse-exfat`.

([source](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/107689/how-do-i-access-exfat-files/))